# how to include custom asset in rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I got  javascript errors when upgraded from 4.0 to 4.1

I put `ace-admin-theme` and `lenord-single-page-theme` folders under `app/assets/`

And add the following in `config/application.rb`

```
 29     config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/ace-admin-theme"
 30     config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/lenord-single-page-theme"




.
├── ace-admin-theme
│   ├── avatars
│   ├── css
│   ├── font
│   ├── images
│   ├── img
│   └── js
├── images
├── javascripts
│   └── application.js
├── lenord-single-page-theme
│   ├── css
│   ├── fonts
│   ├── img
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── js
│   └── rs-assets
└── stylesheets
    ├── application.css.scss
    ├── custom.css.scss
    ├── layout.css.scss
    ├── scaffolds.css.scss
    ├── users.css.scss
    └── welcome.css.scss
```

I need to include hundreds of css and javascript in my `app/views/layouts/application.html.haml`

```
  2 %html
  3   %head
  4     %title GooodTheme
  5     = stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true
  6     = javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true
  7     / Description, Keywords and Author
 11     %meta{content: "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0", name: "viewport"}/
 12     / Styles
 13     / Bootstrap CSS
 14     %link{href:  asset_path("css/bootstrap.min.css"), rel: "stylesheet"}/
 15     / Slider Revolution CSS
 16     %link{href:  asset_path("css/rs-settings.css"), rel: "stylesheet"}/
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1) If your custom folder falls under the standard assets path (app/assets, lib/assets & vendor/assets) then you dont need to to config.assets.path.

2) Place the folder specific assets like javascripts, css, images, fonts etc under the standard path. ie. place css under assets/css and javascripts under assets/javascripts

Comment: but I want to keep the original whole folder, it has hundreds of files I don't want to mix the two folders' content together :D

Comment: add folders 'ace-admin-theme' and 'lenord-single-page-theme' under the asset types(css,js,fonts & images) and place the respective assets there. ie. namescope them.